# How to integrate SCIM Server (Basic Auth) with SailPoint IIQ?

Tags: okta, scim, sailpoint

I am running Okta's Example SCIM (v2.0) Server and I wish to know how to integrate it with SailPoint IIQ.
It asks for the Basic Authentication username and password. However, the example app has not authentication configured.
Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you're using the [Python version of Okta's Example SCIM server](https://github.com/oktadeveloper/okta-scim-beta) (which has no authentication) I would suggest using the [Flask Snipped on HTTP Basic Auth](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/) as a guide for adding authentication to the sample.